# How does instanceof with generics work in Java despite type erasure?

Tags: java, generics, instanceof

I've been under the impression that in Java, the `instanceof` operator cannot be used with generics due to type erasure. However, the first conditional statement in my code snippet below compiles and runs without any errors. Can anyone shed light on why the first conditional doesn't cause a compile-time error? I'm using IntelliJ IDEA with Oracle JDK 17.

```java
public class InstanceofTest {
    public static class Tea {}
    public static class Herb {}

    // Why is this working?
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Tea> teas = new ArrayList<>();

        if (teas instanceof List<Tea>) {
            System.out.println("TRUE");
        } else {
            System.out.println("FALSE");
        }

        // Compile error
        // if (teas instanceof List<Herb>) {
        //     System.out.println("TRUE");
        // } else {
        //     System.out.println("FALSE");
        // }
    }
}
```

Comment: IIUC, after type erasure, `List<Tea>` will just become `List` i.e. a list of `Object`

Comment: In the example, the compiler **knows** it is a `List<Tea>`, so it allows it, which is also why it complains about the `instanceof List<Herb>`, because it knows it cannot ever be true.

Comment: it is a compiler error, not a runtime error - it *indicates* that the compiler *knows* that `List<Tea>` variable should only hold an instance of `List<Tea>`, but a `List<Herb>` can never hold an instance of `List<Tea>`

Comment: @user85421 It can also hold `null`, which would trigger the else branch.

Comment: @user85421 You can't assign an `ArrayList<Herb>` to a `List<Tea>`, Java won't allow you to do that. You can do a reroute with an intermediate cast to List and then to List<Tea>, but if you go through shenanigans like that, then Java will just believe you on your word, and act as if it's a List<Tea> (and because of erasure, it will then print `TRUE` at runtime).

Comment: I'm truly grateful for your detailed and prompt responses! Your explanations have been incredibly helpful in clarifying my understanding. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Java, generics like `List<Tea>`, are reduced to just `List` when your code runs, that's why you generally can't use `instanceof` with a generic type. The reason `instanceof List<Tea>` works is because, at compile time, the Java compiler is only checking against the `List` part of `List<Tea>`. It doesn't care about the `<Tea>` part because of type erasure, but it doesn't throw an error since it's not *wrong* to write it that way, and the syntax itself isn't inccorrect. The compiler is aware that you're dealing with a `List<Tea>` from the context, so it won't object.

On the other hand, when you try `instanceof List<Herb>`, the compiler steps in because it knows your list can't be a `List<Herb>`, since you *told* it it was a `List<Tea>`. This happens at compile time,  based on the information you've provided, regardless of the list's actual content at runtime.

TL;DR: 
Java compiler makes decisions based on the information available at compile time, not on the actual contents of the list during runtime, due to type erasure.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clear explanation. I'm really bummed that my reputation is too low to upvote your answer as useful!

Comment: No worries, my rep is too low as well, but as you ask more questions, (and I answer), well both get enough rep to upvote, etc. :)

Comment: @castarray I believe you should still be able to accept their answer (you may need to wait a bit first, I forget), which will both help future readers and give them some rep. :-)

Comment: @yshavit Absolutely, I'm now fully able to do that. Thanks for reminding me again! 